# How per day messages of chat room is calculated?

Tags: support, chat

I have seen messages per day 300 per day and 20-30 per day also.

How many days it is taking for average?
Is average taken from creation of chat room or last year or last month or last week or last 2 weeks? Is it dependent on number of users visiting room?

[image: messages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "per day" number is based on the past 14 days, the "per week" number on the past 28 days.